# One click rather than two (big deal!)

Tags: feature-request

Yes, two clicks is hardly onerous, but now that SO has a meta all to itself, please consider adding a link somewhere near the top of each meta page that only requires one click to take me to SO (as in chat, where logically it is at the bottom).

Suggestion for possible location for a 'button':
[image]

There is precedent for clicking the logo to change sites (SEDE), but elsewhere convenient would be good enough location for a button.

[Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369680/link-back-to-so-from-meta-so#comment601420_369680).

Comment: You're making a feature request, while acknowledging that the current functionality works fine, and the change would save very little effort? Well... Okay. Good luck with that.

Comment: Isn't that what feature requests are for? *features*? Had he labeled it bug I would have something to say but as a feature request this makes sense.

Comment: @rlemon Well, yeah.I just find it interesting that his tack is "I think it says something bad about how lazy I am for even thinking to ask this, but..." I actually have nothing against either this feature or the OP, it's simply that the marketing style amused me.

Comment: @pnuts You have my +1.

Comment: @pnuts WHAT? This commie pro-fun agenda has gone too far. Now, it's on the internet, soon it'll be in our schools- thank god we can at least count on c-span to keep that kind of tomfoolery in check.

Comment: What would you remove from the top bar in order to fit this link in?

Comment: I really didn't understand that at all. Maybe it's because I never use that "Stack Exchange" dropdown. 99% of the time, I navigate to Meta by using my browser's autocomplete. The other 1%, I go to the "Help" menu at the top right.

Answer (score 3):

I expect the logo from a site to return me to the homepage of that site, not the homepage of another site. You can easily switch between the meta, chat and the normal site by opening the dropdown menu in the top-left and choosing the appropriate link.

I honestly see no reason to pollute the interface with another link to meta/normal so/chat. It's already very simple.

Comment: Where is the drop-down on the top-left?  The only one I see got to 'home', 'questions', 'tags', and 'users' on the meta site.  From another comment I see that you can get to the original with the top link under the help button (2nd from the right)...  I guess this is an old question, it just showed up in the feed because it was edited...

Comment: This is a question about the old navigation bar. In the current navigation bar you can open the right-most button (the stack-exchange logo) and navigate to meta/so/chat.