# Please add a link from meta-review back to main-review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design, meta

The last item on the review-queue-list on main is ["Meta Reviews"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review).
Curiously, there's no corresponding link from the review-queue-list on meta back to ["Main Reviews"](https://stackoverflow.com/review), even though that list is *much* shorter.

I suggest adding it for convenience and regularity.

---

[image: List of Review-Queues on main]

[image: List of Review-Queues on meta]

Comment: Hm. [That FR](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258688/one-click-rather-than-two-big-deal) is about adding a one-click-link to get back to main, yes, but to the general site. There's no such link on main either, so no asymmetry. I'm not even sure where one would logically put such a link on main/meta.

Comment: It didn't actually solve my problem, but that might take 6-8 months longer.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question... and is a feature I would like to see also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 6 to 8 weeks this takes to implement use the following userscript to add the link to the review dashboard on meta:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         link to main review
// @namespace    http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene
// @version      0.2
// @description  link back to main
// @author       rene
// @match        *://meta.stackoverflow.com/review
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

/*global $ */

/*global $ */

(function($) {
    $('#content div.grid--cell.fl1')
        .last()
        .append($('<div class="dashboard-item"><div class="dashboard-count"><\/div><div class="dashboard-summary"><div class="dashboard-title"><a href="//stackoverflow.com/review">Stack Overflow Reviews<\/a><\/div><div class="dashboard-description">Visit the review queues on Stack Overflow.<\/div><\/div><br class="cbt"><\/div>'));
})($);
```

tested on Chrome, with Tamper Monkey.

Comment: This is not working for me (Tamper Monkey + Chrome + SO Meta)

Comment: @ArunVinoth I've updated the code to handle the new id and css classes

Comment: Fantastic.. thank you for this awesome work. :)